# qt5/qml: how to implement advanced/addon/details switch?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I want implement such GUI element:

> Details ▶

if click on it:

> Details ▼
>
> Other gui elements avaible only if arrow down

Is any existing qml elements can I use to achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked at the [TreeView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html) component?

Comment: @Zak I need only one such element, so `TreeView` should be without frame, caption, and allow insert any view in place of open element (with buttons, checkboxes and other stuff), is it possible?

Comment: Don't think so. Anyway, TreeView has a different purpose. There is no such component, so I would suggest writing you own. It can be a combination of a Text label, Button to expand content and Loader to represent your content.

Comment: If you google for *QML Accordion* you might find a couple of implementations with different benefits and drawbacks. I think there are even a few on this site.

Comment: @derM Thanks, `Accordion` is the word that I am looking for.